# Unexpected keyword argument in Twython.__init__

Tags: python, django, twitter

Request Method: POST

Django Version: 1.5

Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'twitter_secret'

settings.py

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = 'mykey'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'mysecretkey'
TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = 'mytoken'
TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'mytokensecret'
```

views.py

```
from twython import Twython

def publish_tweet(tweet):
twitter = Twython(
    twitter_token=settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    twitter_secret=settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    oauth_token=settings.TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN,
    oauth_token_secret=settings.TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
)
twitter.update_status(status=tweet.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: [Twython API docs](http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) indicate that when you pass `twitter_token` and `twitter_secret`, you probably mean `app_key` and `app_secret`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source code of Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/api.py#L29) the valid keyword arguments are: app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, access_token, token_type,           oauth_version, api_version, client_args and auth_endpoint: so it seems you're making up some keyword argument names, that's why you get the error ** init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'twitter_secret'**. I recommend you following the steps listed in [the docs](http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#authentication).

Comment: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid or expired token